# Laravel return with old input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to return with old input but it's empty.

This is my code.

```
return view('reports.employees.index', compact('employee', 'zones', 'barChart'))->withInput(Input::all());

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="start" placeholder="Tarih" value="{{old('start')}}"/>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `old input` ?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to use old input

Comment: Your question explanation are not enough to understand your problem, please provide more details

Comment: @hassan if you know laravel it means data after a (failed) submit of a form

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following middleware classes in your $middlewareGroups property of App\Http\Kernel class:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
```

And check the link with a similar problem: [Laravel 5 withInput old always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148109/laravel-5-withinput-old-always-empty)

Answer (score 0):

make sur the input array has 'employee', 'zones', 'barChart'  cause compact suppose wait some variable named 'employee', 'zones', 'barChart' .  In your case add start into compact (employee', 'zones', 'barChart','start')